# Remove .html and .html/amp extension with .htaccess only for files from directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After a site move I want to be able to remove the extension (if any) and query string (if any) to leave just the file name and keep the path

`https://www.example.com/blog/anyfile.html`
301 to >> `https://www.example.com/blog/anyfile`

`https://example.com/blog/anyfile.html/amp`
301 to >> `https://www.example.com/blog/anyfile`

`https://www.example.com/blog/anyfile.html/amp?nonamp=1`
301 to >> `https://www.example.com/blog/anyfile`

I tried something like this, but it doesn't keep the `/blog/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1? [L,NC,R]
```

also, I can't find a way to remove `/amp` after `.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file you could do something like the following to discard `.html` and `.html/amp` and `.html/<anything>` from the end of the URL-path. And discard the query string (if any) at the same time:

```
# Strip ".html" onwards from the end of the URL (and remove query string)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html(/.*)?$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is preferable to appending an empty query string in order to remove the query string on Apache 2.4+.

You need to hardcode the scheme + hostname if you wish to satisfy your second example and redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. This could be generalised (without hardcoding the domain) if we know that your site is only accessible by the www subdomain or domain apex and this single domain.

However, the above won't catch URLs that only include a query string, but don't contain `.html` in the URL-path. For that you could implement an additional rule, *following* the rule above:

```
# Strip the query string from any URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

---

A look at your existing rule:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
> RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1? [L,NC,R]
> ```

You are only capturing the filename (`anyfile` in your example) and discarding the URL-path that precedes this (ie. `blog/`). So the `$1` backreference only contains `anyfile`. This also only matches URLs that end in `.html` and not `.html/amp`.

Checking the URL-path in the `RewriteCond` directive is superfluous.